# Изменение размера Conteiner View в зависимости от его содержимого

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, view

Есть **ViewController**->**ScrollView**->**ContentView**->**[View]**

В **ContentView** лежат различные **UI** элементы констрейны настроены.

Так-же в **ContentView** есть **Conteiner View** который встраивает в себя VC2 (динамическая таблица).

Какой существует способ изменять размер Conteiner View в зависимости от изменений размера таблицы в VC2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Просто изменяйте размер view самого вложенного VC. Это можно сделать, например, в методе `viewDidLayoutSubviews` с помощью изменения констрейнта на height.